# sql not null property error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql table and here is my column which gives error. When I try to add a new record which has null active_status to this table, It gives "not-null property references a null or transient value" error. Is there any idea?

```
active_status character varying(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NEW'::character varying,
```

**EDIT:** I have created a new simple table;

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
"MyData" character varying(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'NEW'::character varying,
CONSTRAINT mytable_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("MyData" )
)
WITH (
 OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE mytable
OWNER TO postgres;
```

When I try to insert a string, it runs fine;

```
insert into mytable values('ssss');
```

But when I try to insert a null value it gives error;

```
insert into mytable values(null);

ERROR: null value in column "MyData" violates not-null constraint
SQL state: 23502
```

Comment: Please show the full error message and the insert statement?

Comment: @muistooshort Here is my simple new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this statement:

```
insert into mytable values(null);
```

you explicitely *requested* to insert a NULL value into the column MyData and therefor you get the error message.

If you want to use the default value, you need to tell the DBMS to do so:

```
insert into mytable values (default);
```

Btw: it is much better coding style to always specify the columns in the insert statement:

```
insert into mytable ("MyData") values (null);
```

And another thing: you should avoid using quoted identifiers (`"MyData"` vs. `MyData`) , they simply are more trouble than it's worth it.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was about to say. Might be worthwhile to send them to the [INSERT documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-insert.html) for other ways to handle default values though.

Comment: I get it thanks. I removed not-null constraint but now How can I say db to "If user tries to inserts null value insert it with default value".

Comment: @hellzone: the only way to change the data sent from the user would be a trigger. The better way of course is to not sent data you do not want to save in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create the column with NULL constraint. Update all rows for that column with the default values. Alter the column to have Not Null constraint